# Incompatible Type: __main__.TestClass; expected example.TestClass; Passing 'self' to function in another module

Tags: python, mypy

### Background

I have two modules. Module 1 (`example`) defines `TestClass`. Module 2 (`example2`) defines functions `change_var` which takes an argument `TestClass`. `example` has a method `change` which calls `change_var` from `example2` and passes `self` as argument.

`example2` uses `TYPE_CHECKING` from `typing` to ensure cyclic import does not appear at run-time, but still allows MYPY to check types.

At the call to `change_var` from within `change`, MYPY gives the error `Argument 1 to "change_var" has incompatible type "__main__.TestClass"; expected "example.TestClass"`.

Python Version: `3.7.3`,
MYPY Version: `0.701`

### Example Code

`example.py`

```py
from example2 import change_var


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.test_var = 1

    def change(self) -> None:
        change_var(self)
```

`example2.py`

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from example import TestClass


def change_var(obj: "TestClass") -> None:
    obj.test_var = 2
```

This code is a minimal example of the actual problem I am experiencing in a larger python project.

### What I Expect this to do

These types should match as they are (as far as I can tell) the same.

My intuition as to why this doesn't work is that `TestClass`, at the point of calling to `change_var` isn't fully defined? For the same reason I can't refer to `TestClass` as a type within `TestClass` itself, I can't pass a `TestClass` object to a function that expects a `TestClass` object from withing the class itself. To MYPY, this is not a full class yet so it uses some kind of placeholder type. This is only an intuition though.

### Questions

1. What *exactly* is the problem here?
2. What is the best work around to achieve this general code structure (two modules, class in one, function that takes class in other, method calls to function) while still making MYPY happy?

I am also open to refactoring this example entirely but I'd like to try to stick to this general structure.

Comment: Do I intuit correctly that there is an `if __name__=='__main__':` in `example.py`?

Comment: I checked the example code in via interpreter so not in the example code. In the larger project, yes, but neither of the files that the example represents are in the module that has the `if __name__=='__main__'`.

Comment: You “checked [it] in”?  The important thing is whether `example.py` is being used as a script (not just `import`ed as a module).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I figured out the problem. The checker that I had which called MYPY used the `--command` flag to pass in the contents of the current file. Running MYPY on the file from the command line resulted in no error. Removing the `--command` flag fixed this error. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of many cases of breakage from treating a module as a **script** (whether via `-m`, `-c` (or `--command` for mypy), or simply `python …/module.py`).  It works only for trivial applications that do not care about the **identity** of the types or functions they create.  (They must also avoid side effects on import and mutable global state, but those are good ideas anyway.)

The solution, beyond “don’t do that”, is to use `__main__.py` in a package.  Even that is not without issues, since certain naïve recursive importers will import it as if it were a true module.